# Passing regular expression from C# to Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net

In my code I am passing the following regex from VB.net to javascript for Post Box address validation.
I am passing the following regex from VB.net

```
^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)
```

It works good in javascript. But its not case sensitive, it fails when we enter capital letters.

I tried the following regex for case insensitive, but it fails completely.

```
^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)/i
```

My requirement is that I need to pass the RegEx from VB.net to javascript.
Any help?

Comment: You should show how you are passing it to JavaScript.

Comment: I am passing it as string from VB.net like hdnPOBOX.value = "regex here......".  in Javascript I am calling it like  var rex = new RegExp($('#<%=hdnPOBOX.ClientID%>').val());

Comment: I know the issue is with 'I' at the end. if I remove 'i' from the end it works but , then it becomes case sensitive. I want it should work for both cases.

Comment: Then you need to output `new RegExp(...yourstuff..., "i");` as `i` is specified as an argument. (`/.../i` is for literal RegExps)

Comment: if you check my above code , If I pass 'i' at the end it fails completely

Comment: Your passing `/i` which is not valid in this case as your using a RegExp constructor. A case insensitive search for `X` looks like `var rex = new RegExp("^X$", "i");` or alternatively `var rex = /^X$/i;`

Comment: It works great, thanks for your help. Make your comment as an answer, I will make it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `/i` would only work if you were using the literal syntax:

```
var rex = /^X$/i;
```

As you are calling the RegExp constructor you need to provide the `i` option as an argument:

```
var rex = new RegExp("^X$", "i");
```